# require/include php file in add_menu()

Tags: admin, admin-menu, admin-bar

I'm creating a custom WP Admin Bar menu item with custom HTML inside the dropdowns. Referring to this: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Admin_Bar/add_menu

the HTML i want to use is quite extensive so I created a separate php file for that HTML. Then I'm trying to include that PHP file inside the menu item, but it's not printing/echoing properly. Right now, all the shows inside the menu item is a 1, and the content is getting printed later on in the DOM of the page.

Here's the code I have:

```
$admin_bar->add_menu( 
    array(
        'id'    => 'dh_row_layouts-content',
        'parent' => 'dh_row_layouts',
        'meta'  => array(        
            'class' => 'dh_hack',
            'html' => include('docs/row_layouts.php'),
        ),
    )
);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn on output buffering, `include` (and evaluate) the PHP file, and save the output (of the evaluated code) in a variable, like so:

```
ob_start();
include 'docs/row_layouts.php';
$html = ob_get_clean();
```

Then just use `'html' => $html` in the `meta` array when you call the `$admin_bar->add_menu()`.

Or if you *don't* need to evaluate any PHP code in the file, you could use `file_get_contents()`:

```
'html' => file_get_contents( 'docs/row_layouts.php' )
```

And you may need to or better use a full absolute path.